# What type specs are allowed when reading json into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, jsonschema

I want to use the `pandas.read_json()` function to import data into a pandas dataframe and I'm going to use `table` for the `orient` parameter in order to be able to provide data type information. In this case the input json has a `schema` property which can be used to specify input metadata, like this:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "col1",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      {
        "name": "col2",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "col3",
        "type": "integer"
      }
    ],
    "primaryKey": [
      "col1"
    ]
  },
  "data": [...]
}
```

However, the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) (section "Encoding with Table Schema") does not elaborate on what kind of type specifications I can use. The "schema" property name suggests that maybe the type specs from [json schema](https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/basic_types/) are supported? Can anyone confirm or otherwise provide info on the supported type specs?

Comment: What makes you believe pandas has anything to do with or uses JSON Schema?

Comment: @Relequestual, since for the `table` orient in `pandas.read_json()` there is a `schema` property in the input json it seems pretty natural to me to assume that it uses the type specs from json schema. But since it isn't documented in the pandas docu this is only an educated guess; I'm not expecting anything - I would just like to know what kind of type specs are supported.

Comment: I wouldn't assume anything that isn't documented. Looks like it depends on the object you're looking at. For example DataFrame types are defined here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html

Comment: I've never heard of `pandas` before today, but I do know JSON Schema. I can't see any link. Sorry.

Comment: @Relequestual, I know about the dataframe dtypes but since they aren't mentioned in the `pandas.read_json()` docu (which is about importing 'foreign' data) that would also be an assumption. My original question appears to have been misleading: I don't particularly care about json schema and as said before, I just want to know what type specs are supported. -> edited my question accordingly

Comment: It looks like there's such a thing as "Table Schema": http://specs.frictionlessdata.io/table-schema/ - I'd guess that since pandas use caps in their docs, this is what they mean. Shame they don't link to it though.

Comment: (Interestingly, frictionlessdata uses JSON Schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table schema that applies for `orient`='table' in both `pandas.read_json()` and `Dataframe.to_json()` is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#table-schema).

Comment: @TomAugspurger pointed that page out to me - thanks a lot for that!

Comment: And, @Relequestual, it does even have a link to the frictionlessdata "Table Schema" on which it is based.